# How do I get a KCL equation involving Vin in this circuit?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, bjt, transfer-function, small-signal

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWIlJv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've been scratching my head with this one. The circuit below is a small signal equivalent circuit of a PNP CB amplifier. I'm trying to get the transfer function Vout/Vin. I was already able to find Vout/Vbe using KCL across the node Vout. Now i'm stuck with the equation for Vin. Could anybody help me get started?

Here is what I got for Vout/Vbe where Rout = R3//R4:

$$\frac{v_{out}}{v_{be}}= \frac{g_{m}R_{out}*1-\frac{sC_{2}}{g_{m}}
}{1+sR_{out}C_{2}} $$

Edit: I made quite the mistake in the schematic.

Edit(2): Here is the old schematic:

[image]

Comment: What KCL equation have you written for the node at the junction of `Rin`, `R1` and `gmVbe` ? Eliminate `Vbe` from that node equation using the `vout/vbe` transfer function.

Comment: @AJN Wouldn't that node be Ve? But i don't know what Ve is. Or would it be Veb? Not really sure.

Comment: For a CB configuration C1 would always be a lot bigger than C2 so that would simplify things a bit. I'm saying this because any simple model of a BJT is going to be no better than 70% accurate. Also, you have Vbe on a node but that node is the base. The emitter should be the north side of Rin as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I get a KCL equation involving Vin in this circuit?

**KCL** equations involve currents, not voltages, that said this might be the answer you are looking for..

In the case of your circuit there is only one **KCL** equation which can be made to involve \$ Vin \$, namely the sum of the currents into the node between \$ R1 \$, \$ Rin \$ and the current source: \$ I_{R1} + I_{Rin} + gm V_{be} = 0\$ **(1)**

now from ohm's-law; \$ I_{R1} = \frac{V_{R1}}{R1} \$ **(2)** and \$ I_{Rin} = \frac{V_{Rin}}{R_{in}} \$ **(3)**

substituting **(2)** and **(3)** into **(1)**; \$ \frac{V_{R1}}{R_{1}} + \frac{V_{Rin}}{R_{in}} + gm V_{be} = 0 \$ **(4)**

to get \$ V_{in} \$ involved we can apply **KVL** to the mesh involving the voltages across the two resisors; \$ V_{in} - V_{Rin} + V_{R1} - V_{be} = 0 \Leftrightarrow V_{in} + V_{R1} - V_{be} = V_{Rin} \$ **(5)**

substituting **(5)** into **(4)**; \$ \frac{V_{R1}}{R_{1}} + \frac{V_{in} + V_{R1} - V_{be}}{R_{in}} + gm V_{be} = 0 \$ **(6)**

And now you have a **KCL** equation **(6)** involving \$ V_{in} \$

Here the reference directions are taken such that all currents into the node are possitive, and the voltage reference directions follow from the standard conventions.

**EDIT;** The OP made a mistake in the schematic,

after the correction equation **(1)** has to be; \$ I_{C1} + I_{R1} + I_{Rin} + gm V_{be} = 0\$ **(1b)**

and equation **(6)** becomes; \$ I_{C1} + \frac{V_{R1}}{R_{1}} + \frac{V_{in} + V_{R1} - V_{be}}{R_{in}} + gm V_{be} = 0 \$ **(6b)**,

to find \$ I_{C1} \$ we need to use that; \$ I_{C1} = C_1 \frac{d}{dt} V_{C1} \$ **(7)**,

since \$ V_{C1} = V_{R1} \$ **(8)** substituting **(8)** into **(7)** we can write this as; \$ I_{C1} = C_1 \frac{d}{dt} V_{R1} \$ **(9)**.

substituting **(9)** into **(6b)** yields; \$ C_1 \frac{d}{dt} V_{R1} + \frac{V_{R1}}{R_{1}} + \frac{V_{in} + V_{R1} - V_{be}}{R_{in}} + gm V_{be} = 0 \$ **(10)**

or if you want the solution in the laplace/s -domain; \$ s C_1  V_{R1} + \frac{V_{R1}}{R_{1}} + \frac{V_{in} + V_{R1} - V_{be}}{R_{in}} + gm V_{be} = 0 \$ **(10b)**.

**Comment; Please do not remove your previous picture etc, but add the new one as an edit!**

Comment: Thanks! I understand your solution but I actually made quite the mistake in my presented schematic which I have corrected now. C1 wasn't suppose to be grounded. How would C1 appear in the equation with Vin? Should I just add the current flowing through C1 as Ic1 = Vbe*sC1 in the sum of currents equation?

Comment: @Rein I have updated my answer to reflect your correction, please do not remove your old scematic but add the new one as an edit!!!

Comment: Thanks so much! I will bring back the old schematic too!

Comment: I noticed that you had Vbe and Vr1 as two different voltages. Shouldn't they be the same?

Comment: @Rein No they should not be the same, V_be is a node voltage compared to GND where as V_r1 is the voltage across R1..

Comment: Thanks I understand now. It's just that for most small signal schematics that I see, Vbe is the same as Vr1, but its because the emitter junction is directly connected to the ground.

Comment: @Rein I am only answering based on the particular schematic that you provided, not based on "most small signal schematics" ;)..